# Is SSIS able to query flat files from another Windows Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, business-objects

I'm pretty new SQL Server Integration Server (SSIS) user.

Is SSIS able to query data from text files located in another Windows Server?

I mean that when SSIS is installed on Windows Server A, is SSIS able to query data from e.g. one folder containing text files in Windows Server B (under same domain)?

I have used only SAP BO Data Integrator ETL tool and it cannot query flat files from another Server: during execution, all files must be located on the Job Server machine that executes the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can access text files on another server using SSIS by using a fileshare and accessing the files using the share name i.e. `\\ServerB\MySSISFiles\`.

You need to make sure that the account the SSIS is running under has access to the file share.

Comment: can I access the file If I m on a different domain, and running with a different user, can I impersonate a user id in SSIS which has access to the shared folder.